Using Separate Auth Models for Organizer and Admin in Django with JWT Authentication
I am working on a project named Event Nest where I have implemented separate authentication models for organizers and administrators. My approach is as follows:
I created an Organizer model using AbstractBaseUser and a custom manager.
I use the predefined User model for admin purposes only.
I have implemented JWT authentication for API endpoints.
Here is my Organizer model:
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

class OrganizerManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
         ....
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        ....
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

class Organizer(AbstractBaseUser):
 *Fields here*

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = OrganizerManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_superuser

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return self.is_superuser

In settings.py, I set the custom user model:
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authenticate_.Organizer'

Problem:
I created APIs for the organizers, and these APIs require JWT authentication. Here is an example endpoint:
/auth/organizer/CreateEvents
When I hit this endpoint with a valid JWT token, I receive an error:

User is not authenticated.

However, if I set AUTH_USER_MODEL to appname.Organizer, the JWT authentication works, and data is created. The issue is that now my User model cannot be used for admin purposes, as the Organizer model is being used for both admins and organizers.
Question:
How can I configure Django to use the Organizer model for organizer-specific authentication while keeping the User model for admin purposes? Is there a way to make both models work together seamlessly with JWT authentication?
Moreover, You can suggest me different approaches too.
If my approach to such scenario is wrong, then I would have to erase everything I have done and start from better approach.
